# Where can I find historical aerials for some areas in Dona Ana County, New Mexico?

Tags: data-request, usa, images, historical, aerial-photography

How do I find several historical aerials from the mid-1970's or early 1980's and where can I download them and I would like them to be free of charge.

[image: Dona Ana County]

[image: Near Anthony, Texas]

[image: Near Hatch, New Mexico]

Comment: are you looking for map or photo?

Comment: Yeah aerial photos or photos are the same thing... Thanks.

Comment: check nasa's sites for free. they do a number of imaging techniques from satellites. eros, and visible earth are two off the top of my head. EDIT: visible earth is down, but you can always use the wayback machine, thats what i've done.

Comment: No mention of historical aerial photos ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

USGS [EarthExplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) is often a fantastic resource for this.

Check out, in particular, these datasets:

- Aerial Photo Single Frames (usually pre-1980)
- DOQ (1990s)
- NAPP (1980s-1990s)
- NHAP (1970s-1980s)

Answer (score 5):

Not free, but UNM has an archive here: https://edac.unm.edu/image-archive/